# Easily see image dimensions while drawing in Powerpoint?

Tags: images, microsoft-powerpoint, dimensions

How can I easily see/use the image dimensions while drawing in Powerpoint? I believe these dimensions are called 'points' but regardless of terminology, my point is that I want to be able to see/use those numbers *while drawing* in Powerpoint. When using "Get Info" these numbers are seen under Dimensions as shown below, although no units are given:

[image]

When I say I want to see/use those numbers, I mean I want to either (1) have grid lines or something like that so that Powerpoint's convenient "snap to" feature helps me see I'm making objects near specific dimensions, say in steps of 100. Alternatively, I'd like to (2) see something like what you see when you resize a selected rectangular region within the Preview app as shown here:

[image]

I've spent a lot of time searching for a SIMPLE solution to this problem and found a lot of people asking about it. The best work around I've found so far involves selecting an image that I've drawn, going to the Shape Format ribbon and typing in the numbers I want followed by "pt" ([as described here, though I guess 'px' is used in Windows](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nvK98cEtcCs)). I find the images produced are often off, for example 1999pt instead of 2000pt, and this doesn't address my goal of wanting to know the size *while drawing*.

Because I don't know any other way to do this, I've ended up using a custom grid consisting of many 100pt squares a Powerpoint template. Awkward solution in many ways.

Answer (score 0):

Powerpoint shows you dimensions in inches or cm, depending on your system settings. Both Windows and Mac PPT allow you to type in units followed by pt (for points), px (for pixels), in (inches), cm or mm .... you get the idea.

Your best bet might be to rightclick the shape you're working with and choose Size & Position to open the pane shown below. You'll probably have to click a couple of the triangles to get both the Size and Position sections open.

The various readouts will give you the info you want for your shape (though they don't update live as you move/size a shape, unfortunately; you have to stop first, which means making your changes incrementally).

[image: PowerPoint Size & Position pane]

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting my solution to demonstrate the best work-around I've found, although I'm still hoping someone has a better suggestion.
[image]
Notice that in the animated gif (click for more detail) Powerpoint's convenient red, dashed guide lines feature helps me see I'm making a square that is 500x500 ***while I'm drawing***.

Here are the elements of this work-around:

1) The 100pt grid in the background was constructed using ppt and then exported as a .jpg

2) It was dragged back into ppt, copied, and set as the slide background using Design-->Format Background-->Picture or Texture Fill-->Clipboard

3) The numbers and rectangles you see at right were made in ppt, grouped, copied and rotated to make those at top

4) This is saved as a template, and I keep the template in my dock for quick access

Typically I keep those numbers & rectangles grouped to minimize accidentally selecting them. However, since grouping prevents seeing Powerpoint's red, dashed guide lines, I ungroup them when I want those.

As mentioned in my original post, this work-around is an "Awkward solution in many ways", and I still hope someone will post a better solution. If you master ppt, it's really a good drawing tool -- but this particular limitation is a problem.